# Magento CatalogSearch Model Problem - Unable to use loadByQueryText();

Tags: module, magento-1, search

I am writing a custom module, and in this module I need to add a search query to the database if it's not there already. I figured out what I need to do:

1. Load `catalogsearch/query` model
2. Check if query exists, if not add it

Here's the code I thought would work:

```
$querymodel = Mage::getModel('catalogsearch/query');
$querymodel->loadByQueryText('testing 123');

if (!$querymodel->getId()) {
    $querymodel->setIsActive(1);
    $querymodel->setQueryText('testing 123');
    $querymodel->setStoreId(1);
    $querymodel->setIsProcessed(0);
    $querymodel->save();
}
```

This code is successful in that it adds to the catalogsearch_query table. However the initial check `loadByQueryText()` or `loadByQuery()` simply does not return true even when a query exists - so I keep getting the same query added to the db.

I've looked through the model file (`Catalogsearch/Model/Query.php`) and I'm using the method in the exact same context as the model itself, so I don't know why it doesn't work?

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up getting it working in a less clean way - no idea why the loadByQueryText() method is stuill not working.

```
$querymodel = Mage::getModel('catalogsearch/query')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('query_text', 'testing 123')
    ->getFirstItem();
```

This returns a result so I'm gonna use it.

Comment: I get [{"query_id":"9225","query_text":"chevrolet","num_results":"0","popularity":2,"redirect":null,"synonym_for":null,"store_id":"0","display_in_terms":"1","is_active":"0","is_processed":"0","updated_at":"2014-07-11 21:03:17"}] as data (printed as json) - i never get results - why? (front-end searchs return expected results)

Answer (score 6):

You are able to tell Magento with field to use on load. The following code should allow you to tell catalogsearch/query to load by the query_text attribute.

```
$querymodel = Mage::getModel('catalogsearch/query');
$querymodel->load('test 123','query_text');
```

Comment: Didn't know that - what happens if there's more than 1? Does it automatically become a collection?

Comment: It seems to only ever return a single object. In the case of the 'catalogsearch/query' model it appears to take the store id into account.

Answer (score 2):

I've done the following in order to debug:

```
$querymodel = Mage::getModel('catalogsearch/query');
$querymodel->loadByQueryText('test');
$data = $querymodel->getData();
print_r($querymodel->getData());
```

And if the record exists, the output is:

```
Array
(
    [query_id] => 54120
    [query_text] => test
    [num_results] => 1
    [popularity] => 1
    [redirect] => 
    [synonym_for] => 
    [store_id] => 6
    [display_in_terms] => 1
    [is_active] => 1
    [is_processed] => 0
    [updated_at] => 2013-01-08 03:55:26
)
```

In your code `if (!$querymodel->getId()) {` should be `if (!$querymodel->getQueryId()) {` or look at the value returned by `$querymodel->getData()`

Comment: That seems to be the problem. When I do print_r($querymodel->getData()); the array is empty. If I load my model by ID it works fine, but it seems loadByQueryText/loadByQuery is somehow damaged.

Comment: which version are you using? On 1.7 works fine on my end (clean 1.7 install).

Comment: 1.5.0.1 - Not a clean install, but I can't see anything which should affect that method. I'm gonna have to have a sift through my files.